# Binding properties of ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm a bit new to WPF and I've run into a problem I haven't been able to find a solution for.

I've implemented an ICollectionView of an IEnumerable list of a custom class.  I can bind a combo box to the ICollectionView and everything works exactly as I want with the exception that elements in the combo box show up as the namespace and object name.  I need to bind the display for the items in the combo box to a property within the object of each item in the enumerable.

Basically the custom object has a string "Name" property I need to show up in the combo box, but I'm having trouble finding any examples on how to do that.

Comment: Please show your WPF that does the binding, and it would be helpful to see the class you are binding to (as  well as the collection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the `DisplayMemberPath` property on the ComboBox? For example, to display the 'Name' property in your ComboBoxItems, you'd write something along the lines of this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ComboBox>
```

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.